# Does Mac OSX keep a log of network connection addresses and data transfers statistics for all of my browsing activity?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac

I'm trying to find logs of host addresses my computer has connected with over time as well as the corresponding counts of sent/received bytes for each of these connections. For example, the `nettop` command line tool shows readout of network connection addresses and data transfer rates, which refreshes every couple of seconds:

```
                                                               interface           state        bytes in       bytes out   rx dupe    rx ooo     re-tx   rtt avg   rcvsize    tx win
Dropbox.365                                                                                     4928 KiB        3340 KiB  4498 B      13 KiB  6832 B
    tcp4 192.168.1.101:50635<->162.125.33.7:443                      en0       CloseWait        3784 B          1681 B       0 B       0 B       0 B    87.75 ms   128 KiB    32 KiB
    tcp4 192.168.1.101:50605<->162.125.4.3:443                       en0       CloseWait          16 KiB         941 B    1005 B       0 B       0 B     8.62 ms   128 KiB    30 KiB
```

I'm looking for files containing this same information logged over time, e.g., the complete set of network connection addresses and data transfers for the past 24 hours -- or the past week. Does the Mac OSX system maintain long term logs of such network activity?

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised if it did (unless you have some third-party firewall software).

Comment: @grawity So do you think `nettop` just grabs a sample from from the connection traffic without saving anything then?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does.